# MSP430 G2553 TimerA Compare Mode for IR receiver

Tags: timer, msp430, receiver, infrared

My Infrared-Receiver sends me digital data on Port P1.1. I already have my Timer configured that if theres a falling or rising edge a interrupt gets triggered. I wanna know how i get the actual time difference between the edges. Afterwards i wanna save them in an array.

Main:

```
// Stop watchdog timer
WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;

//1mhz = 0.000001
BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ;               // load calibrated data
DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;

//Define Outputs
P1DIR = green_led+red_led+IR_Send;
P2DIR = LED1+LED2+LED3;

//Define Inputs
P1DIR &= ~IR_Recv;

//Set IR_Recv as input for Timer (TA0.CCI0A)
P1SEL |= BIT1;

//Timer_A using SMCLK/8 = 0.000008s and Continuous mode
TACTL = TASSEL_2 | MC_2 | ID_3;

// falling edge and rising edge capture mode, CCI0A, enable IE
CCTL0 = CM_3 | CCIS_0 | CAP | CCIE;

//Enter LPM and enable Global Interrupts
__bis_SR_register(CPUOFF + GIE);
```

Interrupt Routine:

```
//gets called when falling or rising edge is detected on IR_Recv
#pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A (void)
{
if(edgeCount < 10){
    rxData[edgeCount] = TACCR0;
    TACCR0 = 0;
}
edgeCount++;

P2OUT ^= LED2;
//Clear interrupt Flag
TACCTL0 &= ~CCIFG;
//go back to LPM
__bic_SR_register_on_exit ( CPUOFF );
}
```

Comment: So you have `rxData[0]` and `rxData[1]`, and want to know the interval between them?

Comment: exactly. Is TACCR0 even the right register to get the current "time"? and how do i only start the timer when my first edge is received?

Comment: So, for example, if `rxData[0]` has the value `1010`, and `rxData[1]` has the value `1234`, you want to know how many ticks have elapsed between them? (`224`)

Comment: yea but if i read them out in debug mode there are weird values in there... Im doing probably something wrong...

Comment: Define "weird". Is the difference wrong?

Comment: - values for example, probably an overflow right... is the TACCR0 the right register to get the timervalue? this timer is so confusing with all his different registers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the time difference, in ticks, between two captured events, just let the timer keep running without resetting it, and subtract the captured time stamps:

```c
uint16_t difference = rxData[1] - rxData[0];
```

This computation is correct even when the timer counter happens to overflow.

Comment: As you can see in my code im setting TACCR0 every edge to 0 so im getting every interrupt the exact value of the timer since the last edge was detected... am i wrong?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention to remove that. (Resetting the timer in software will introduce latencies and reduce the accuracy.)

Comment: I changed my code like you said and received with 2 different remotes 25 timestamps. But the data still looks weird... it looks linear and two different keys on the remote look nearly identical..Heres some Screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/lucQi

Comment: `rxPulse[0]` never changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help man! That solved my issue. I have one more question though: Do you think 25 cycles are enough to receive the whole Signal? and 1mhz should be more than enough precise, right?

Comment: This depends on the IR protocol (whatever that may be).

Comment: I am working on a similar project and haven't used a capture/compare interrupt before. How does the ISR above capture both the rising and falling edges? Or does it only catch one?

Comment: @Jenks Look up `CM_3`.